# Выбрать последнии элементы массива с одинаковым значением

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив, в этом массиве есть поле 'quantity' - количество, сейчас это количество передается в БД, проблема в том что если выбрать 2 товара одним заказом то количество запишется последнего элемента массива, нужно что бы количество было сумма 'quantity' текущего заказа, то-есть нужно как то записать в переменную $Summm1 количество товаров последнего товара, общее у них это поле order_id. Делал так но выдает 0:

```
    $Mazz = end($orderItems);
    $Mazz1 = $Mazz['item']['quantity'];

    $Summm = $Mazz1;

    $Mazz_id = $Mazz['item']['order_id'];

   foreach ($orderItems as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
           if ($v1 = $Mazz_id) {
              $Summm1 = $v['quantity'] + $Summm;
          }
          else {
            $Summm1 = $Summm;
          }
      }
}
```

$Mazz - последний элемент массива (массив заказов)
$Mazz1 - количество последнего заказанного товара

Условие if ($v1 = $Mazz_id) срабатывает, проверил это заменив $v['quantity'] на произвольное число 4. Поэтому скорее всего проблема в $v['quantity'].

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

```
  //  Пробовал еще так

    $Mazz = end($orderItems);
    $Mazz1 = $Mazz['item']['quantity'];

    $Summm = $Mazz1;

    $Mazz_id = $Mazz['item']['order_id'];

   foreach ($orderItems as $k => $v) {
   $prov = 0;
        foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
           if ($v1 == $Mazz_id) {
            $prov = 1;

          }
          if ($k1 == 'quantity' && $prov == 1) {
              $Summm1 = $Summm + $v1;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: а зачем второй цикл? там не один элемент с полем quantity? если так, то нужен один цикл 
```if ($v['order_id'] == $Mazz_id) { $Summm1 = $Summm + $v['quantity']; }```

Answer (score 1):

вы в if выполняете присваивание?, может вы имели ввиду проверку ?
`if ($v1 == $Mazz_id)`

Comment: `else {
            $Summm1 = $Summm;
          }` здесь вы всегда записываете одно и то же значение, немного непонятно какая структура вашего массива, как вариант чтобы понять что там происходит выведите `var_dump()` на каждом этапе и сразу поймете в чем ошибка,

Comment: Подредактировал вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: $Summm1[  ]......