# Передать значение поля в переменную по id

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно передать в переменную $Summm1 количество товаров данного заказа ('quantity'),

```
    $Mazz = end($orderItems);  // последний элемент массива всех заказов
    $Mazz1 = $Mazz['item']['quantity'];  // количество последнего элемента

    $Summm = $Mazz1;

    $Mazz_id = $Mazz['item']['order_id'];  // order_id - id заказа, нужно по нему вытянуть количество

   foreach ($orderItems as $k => $v) {
   $prov = 0;
        foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
           if ($v1 == $Mazz_id) {
            $prov = 1;

          }
          if ($k1 == 'quantity' && $prov == 1) {
              $Summm1 = $Summm + $v1;
          }
      }
}
```

При таком раскладе количество = 0, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передать количество в переменную $Summm1.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбрать последнии элементы массива с одинаковым значением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991560/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так и не понял, зачем вам вложенный цикл, если вы знаете что нужное поле имеет путь `$orderItems[$i]['item']['quantity']`.
что-то такое надо?

```
$mazzId = ...;
$filtered = array_filter($orderItems, function($v) use ($mazzId){ 
                   return $v['item']['order_id'] = $mazzId;
               });
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($v){ return $v['item']['quantity'];}, $filtered));
```

Comment: Спасибо ) Все оказалось намного проще